# Saxon XQueryEvaluator.Evaluate returns TinyElementImpl instead of XdmNode

Tags: c#, xml, performance, xquery, saxon

This is a simplified version of my code

```
Processor processor = new Processor();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
documentBuilder.IsLineNumbering = true;
documentBuilder.WhitespacePolicy = WhitespacePolicy.PreserveAll;
XQueryCompiler compiler = processor.NewXQueryCompiler();
string query = BuildXqueryString();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
{
    XQueryExecutable executable = compiler.Compile(query);
    XQueryEvaluator evaluator = executable.Load();
    evaluator.ContextItem = documentBuilder.Build(xmlNode);
    var evaluations = evaluator.Evaluate();

    foreach (var evaluation in evaluations)
       runEvaluation((XdmNode)evaluation, document);
}
```

This is what I have right now and it works as expected. Right now we are doing some changes to parallelize the evaluations, and I´m having issues modifying the last foreach to change it to a Parallel.ForEach. This is my new code replacing the foreach:

```
List<XdmNode> evaluationsAsList = evaluations.GetList().Cast<XdmNode().ToList();

Parallel.ForEach(evaluationsAsList, evaluation =>
   runEvaluation(evaluation, document)
);
```

This code fails, because `GetList()` is returning me a list of `net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyElementImpl` instead of `Saxon.Api.XdmNode`. According to the documentation `GetList()` should always return at least a `Saxon.Api.XdmItem` list and that is not the case either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to reproduce this but having trouble the following: List<XdmNode> evaluationsAsList = evaluations.GetList().Cast<XdmNode().ToList();
Is it possible that you can send me a repo please. Maybe offline.

Comment: That was just a test to try to get a List of `XdmNode`, I'm not sure if that should be the correct approach. What I want to achieve is to use the result of  `evaluator.Evaluate()` inside a `Parallel.ForEach`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. I've logged it here for action:

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3006

From inspecting the code, it looks to me as if GetList() is wrong in the case where the XdmValue is a singleton XdmItem. So until we produce a fix, you may be able to work around the problem by testing XdmValue.Count and handling the singleton case differently.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with handling the singleton case differently?

Comment: Something like `if (evaluations instanceof XdmNode) then runEvaluations(((XdmNode)evaluations) else ((your current code))`

Comment: Bug now fixed. Patch will be available in the next maintenance release.